Recent and present
How do we know recent and present
I know that present perfect can use present situation and recent action but what I am confused is how to divide them that native speaker is speaking present or recent, how we can know easily?
For example
"I have been busy that I have taken an exam for joining speaking class recently."
In this context I used the key word recently to show recent action and actually right now I am not busy and I already did take exam and I am telling recent action by using present perfect as per grammar, what I did.
"I have been busy that I have taken an exam for joining speaking class."
If I omit recently, I will understand that that context means right now I am taking the exam and I am busy, because present perfect show present situation.
My question is - will a native speaker, use to clear the situation present or recent, by using key words recently, lately, of late or how have you been with present perfect? I can easily understand completed action and experiential action but I can't understand how to divide present or recent.

You can't say "I have been busy that...". A native speaker would probably say "I've been [very] busy recently [because] I took an exam on Friday..." (I'm not sure what an 'exam for joining speaking class' is!)

Yes Madam! Just example level test @Kate Bunting


I know that present perfect can use present situation...

This is not how I would describe it. The perfect forms of a tense primarily refer to the past, but may or may not be still true in the present. This is illustrated by your example. Compare these two sentences:

I have been busy preparing for tomorrow's exam.
I have been busy preparing for yesterday's exam.

With both sentences the form of the tense is the same. However in sentence (1) I may still be busy preparing; in sentence (2) I am no longer busy.
So to answer your specific question, it's not possible from the tense alone to tell if the past action is still happening in the present or the recent past. That element is determined from the overall context of the sentence. In my examples that context is provided by the words 'yesterday' and 'tomorrow'; in your example, by the word 'recently'.

If I omit recently I will understand that that context mean right now I take the exam and I am busy, because present perfect show present situation.

This is not correct. Removing recently simply means that the period is uncertain. "I have been busy preparing for the exam" now has no marker to indicate whether or not I am still busy.

Your example 2  seems strange because if you took the exam yesterday you should not be  busy anymore today and I think using past simple or past perfect would be better

People keep talking about which tense would be better or correct. Often that's the wrong question. We should ask, what tense do I choose to communicate what I want to say? "I was busy preparing for yesterday's exam" is entirely correct, but it doesn't mean the same thing as "I have been busy..."

For example, compare these sentences: (1) "On Saturday I was busy preparing for yesterday's exam, so I didn't answer your phone call." (2) Over the last two weeks I have been busy preparing for yesterday's exam, and I am exhausted. I'm glad it's over!"

yes your second example is clearer for me because now  there is a present result  I am exhausted

Thank you @Peter Kirkpatric

Thank you @Yves Lefol.

@YvesLefol, Let me make another comment about the second example. I did not say have been busy because of the present result. "Have been busy" is still pointing back to the past period. The difference between the two sentences is that in #1 I was busy at a point in time, but in #2 I have been continually busy over the whole period of past time.
